# does server call affects battrey life

Tags: android, cron

I am Working on android  app, I wrote a Cron job on my server side and it send data to android app to every five minute, So my question is does this cron job drain battery of phone ?

Thank you in adavnce

Comment: Since you are sending data from sever(Hope you used GCM to push data to device) the android device won't drain battery much as it is calling a service in every 5 minutes.

Comment: instead GCM I used firebase to push data

Comment: Android keeps one active connection to Google's servers, but it doesn't use much power or data, because no traffic is sent along it until something sends a GCM message to an app on your phone. There's only one connection on the phone, used by all apps: SO even if it is a Firebase it doesn't drain much battery..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will drain your battery if you are requesting the network call in every 5 minutes to update your android app. To optimize it go through this article. 
https://developer.android.com/training/performance/battery/network/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a cron job server side, there is no question of the phone requesting a network call every 5 mins. It "wakes up" only when data is actually sent from your server I guess. So no, it should not affect your battery consumption.